# Android scrollview with list of items

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I want to have a view with the following vertical layout

1. An image (IamgeView)
2. A description of the image (TextView)
3. A list of comments

The constraint is that I want the entire page to scroll and not just the list of comments.
The number of comments may vary. If I use a ListView for the comments the entire screen doesn't scroll.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a header view to your ListView. Whatever you put in the header view will scroll just like the list.